# C# listbox and SQL database

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am working with a project with c# wpf. I have three checkbox, a listbox, and button.
When i check checkbox for example three checkbox the result is appeared in listbox. But what i want to do is that when i click the button register the value from listbox to store in sql database.

XAML code

```
 <Grid>
    <StackPanel Name="panel">
        <CheckBox Name="chb1" Content="USA" />
        <CheckBox Name="chb2" Content="England"  Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
        <CheckBox Name="chb3" Content="Italy"  Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
        <ListBox Name="lx" Height="100"/>
        <Button Name="btn" Content="Click" Width="60" Height="25" Click="btn_Click" />
        <Button Name="register" Content="Register"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And xaml.cs code

```
  lx.Items.Clear();
        foreach (CheckBox checkbox in panel.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(cb => cb.IsChecked == true))
        {
            lx.Items.Add(checkbox.Content);

        }
```

I know how to store just on checkbox content, but when i try to save three checkbox content , in sql is saved just one. Thank YOU anyone who try to help me

Comment: So you are only getting one in SQL and you post none of the SQL code.

Comment: The code to put one value to sql is a simple code, just opening the connection, declare the column in sql where do you want to save, and listbox where do you get data, for that i didn't put the code

Comment: If it was that simple it would be working.

Comment: I can read.  You are a new user and I have a rep over 20K - maybe just maybe I know what I am talking about.  So you post the code that is working - lx.Items.Clear();   And feel not relevant to post the code that is not working?

Comment: lx.Items.Clear();
        foreach (CheckBox checkbox in panel.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(cb => cb.IsChecked == true))
        {
            lx.Items.Add(checkbox.Content);

        }                               this code is used to get the content from selected checkbox and display it in a listbox, it doesnt have to do anything with sql database, is a interface,,,,i am trying to save the results int sql databse.... And also i was a member here one year ago i had some reputation point...... How i see you you got those point just commenting  and trying to be smart

Comment: Voting to close.  Still have not shown code "for but when i try to save three checkbox content , in sql is saved just one"

Comment: ok do want you want, you dont have a sense

Comment: And you still have not shown code "for but when i try to save three checkbox content , in sql is saved just one"

Comment: i dont know if i was clear. The english is not my language, when i click the register button the content of first checkbox is saved in one row in sql, i need just a code that puts also other checkbox in other rows. with one click

Comment: What is so difficult?   Post the code that adds one value to SQL.  Post your  current Register event handler.